# vendor lib inside new github project

Tags: go

I need to publish a new go project into git, I saw that some libraries (like kubernetess )  are commit also the vendor folder with all the 3rd party lib's, what is the reason to do it ?

Comment: Using a dependency manager like [dep](https://golang.github.io/dep/) automatically generates that folder. In that folder there are all of the dependencies the project needs. It helps shipping in a self-contained way.

Comment: Some people track vendor, others keep a lock file. Both have pro's and cons. Personally, I wouldn't track my vendor dir if I have a dependency on things like kubernetes. It creates bloat in your repo, every update of a dependency is going to be shown as a diff, and it's fairly trivial to create a build image that just runs the command to get all your deps at build time. The downside of the latter is that your builds would take longer. Then again, you might have the deps on your local machine, so you could just conditionally run the `dep ensure` or `glide install` command

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Glide is not longer recommended for use. The project page states that one should use dep instead. If one is feeling (a little) adventurous, [vgo](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/vgo) is another option.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I know it's no longer recommended as golang chose `dep` as the standard, doesn't mean people might be using it still. I'm personally inclined to stick with glide until vgo is stable